# Framed / Boxed and underlined Item in itemize?

Tags: beamer, formatting, enumerate

I am preparing a presentation using `beamer` and want to have a listing which looks like the following example:

[image]

Could anyone tell me how this could be achieved in LaTeX?

Thank you for any hint :-).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please write at least the basic framework of your desired code. Like this, we would have to write a complete beamer document for you in order to play around with the code. What have you tried until now? Where are you having problems? Please show some own effort and you will get help very quickly (I suppose). Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if an item spans more than one line? Where should the underlining go in that case?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possibility (I took care of two levels of nesting but the same idea will also apply to the third level):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{enumitem}{RGB}{31,51,87}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{%
  \apptocmd{\@item}{%
    \tikz[overlay]\draw[gray!60] ([yshift=-0.5ex]0,0) -- ++(\linewidth,0);%
  }{}{}}
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{mysquare}
{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
      \tikz[baseline=(nodnum.base)]
        \node[
          draw=black,
          anchor=east,
          overlay,
          fill=enumitem,
          text width=3.25ex,
          align=center,
          minimum height=5ex, 
          font=\scriptsize
        ]  (nodnum)
        {\color{fg}\insertenumlabel};%
  }%
}  
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{mysquare}
{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{subitem projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{subitem projected}%
      \tikz[baseline=(nodnum.base)]
        \node[
          draw=black,
          anchor=east,
          overlay,
          fill=enumitem,
          text width=4ex,
          align=center,
          minimum height=4ex, 
          font=\tiny
        ]  (nodnum)
        {\color{fg}\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel};%
  }%
}  
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[mysquare]  
\makeatother
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subitem.
  \item Second subitem.
  \item Third subitem.
  \item Fourth subitem.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Fourth item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the fourth slide:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure. Why do you load `\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}` if later use `{\color{fg}\insertenumlabel}`? I think `[bg]` is not needed. Or a better option would be `\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}` and `{\insertenumlabel}`.

Comment: thank you so much. That looks quite good. My only main problem is now, how can I deactivate a specific item (i.e. how can I make a specific item gray). It would be great if there is a parameter like (or something like this):

\item[gray] This is an item in gray \item[blue] This is an item in blue

The result should look similar to picture you posted, but I want to determine myself which item is deactivated. Could you tell me, how this is possible?

Thank you in advance :-)